# Write/ReadProcessMemory com offsets

Tags: c#

Estou com dúvidas de como posso fazer para ler/escrever os dados desse ponteiro da imagem abaixo (Cheat Engine):

[image: Pointer]
Minha dúvida é:
Como adicionar o nome do módulo "server.dll" + endereço + offsets?

Código feito:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TrainerTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern Boolean ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, out int lpBuffer, int nSize, int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        private const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
        private int pId = 0;
        private int lpBaseAddress = 0x0058059C;
        private int[] offsetList = new int[] { 0x4, 0x0, 0x280, 0xF0, 0x4B4 };
        private int getAdressValue = 0;
        IntPtr hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Process getProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName("hl2"))
                pId = getProcess.Id;

            if (pId == 0)
                return;

            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pId);
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, out getAdressValue, 4, 0))
                textBox1.Text = getAdressValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Este código funciona usando um simples endereço, mas não um Pointer com offsets, pois eu não sei como fazer esta soma.
Pesquisei e vi que com um loop na array dos offsets consigo gerar o Ponteiro.  Algo como:

```
int calcAddress = 0x0058059C;
for (int x = 0; x < offsetList.Length; x++)
{
    calcAddress += ofsetList[x];
}
```

Mas e quanto ao módulo "server.dll"???